# VS 2010: Add as Link a complete directory of XML to a solution Folder? (no project exists at this level)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I need to add (as link) a complete directory structure that lives under my solution folder but not under any project folder.

Is this possible, i can't seem to find it.

I suppose 1 option is to add a new project type and then add these files under that project..

But it seems not a good way, what type of project type do i add, a c# class project? The files i wish to include are standard XML files and nothing to do with C#

Any ideas or i get around this?

Comment: What if I want to add a directory (not file by file). Once a new file is added to the "real" directory, I want it added automatically to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in **Visual Studio 2010 Professional** and above. You can add a solution folder and then include files within that folder. Just right click the solution in the *Solution Explorer* and choose *Add|New Solution Folder*. Once the folder is added, right-click it and select *Add|Existing Item...* to add each of the files that you want to access from that folder.

Solution folders are symbolic (i.e. they don't have to map to a single physical location) so you can store shortcuts to files from many different file system locations under the same solution folder.